# BeautifulSoup: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When using BeautifulSoup4, I can run this code to get one "Shout" without problems. When I use the `for` loop, I get the error `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'children'`

```
class Shout:
    def __init__(self, user, msg, date):
        self.user = user
        self.msg = msg
        self.date = date

def getShouts():
    #s is a requests Session()
    new_shouts = s.get(shouts_url).text
    #set shouts page as parsable object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new_shouts)
    shouts = []
    shout_heads = soup.find_all("h2", {'class': 'A'})
    shout_feet = soup.find_all("h2", {'class': 'B'})
    for i in range(len(shout_heads)):
        shout = Shout('', '', '')
        shout.user = list(list(list(shout_heads[i].children)[0].children)[1].children)[1].get_text()
        foot = shout_feet[i].get_text().split('-')
        shout.msg = foot[1]
        foot[2] = foot[2].split()
        shout.date = foot[2][0] + " " + foot[2][1]
        shouts.append(shout)
    return shouts
```

What would cause this error to occur only during a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` includes not only the tags in the element but also any *text* (modelled with `NavigableString` objects). Even whitespace can cause there to be text before the first element:

```
<h2>
    <a href="...">Some text</a>
</h2>
```

will have a text node as first child. You'll have to filter those text nodes out, or use `element.find_all(True, recursive=False)` to only list direct child tags. `element.find(True)` finds the *first* child tag, or `None` if there is no such tag.

Or perhaps you can look for more specific tags than just the first child then second child then second chid again; if you have specific tags in mind, then just use their name:

```
shout_heads[i].a.i.span.string
```

for example.

Note that `.children` gives you an iterator; if you wanted a list, *don't use `list()` on `.children`. Use the `.contents` attribute instead, which is a list object.

Last but not least, don't use a loop over `range()` when you can loop over a list directly:

```
for shout_head in shout_heads:
    shout = Shout('', '', '')
    shout.user = shout_head.find(True)[0] # etc.
```

If you needed to combine two lists, you could use `zip()`:

```
for shout_head, shout_foot in zip(shout_heads, shout_feet):
```

although you could also use `find_next_sibling()` to find those extra `h2` elements, if those elements alternate.

Comment: First of all, thank you a ton for helping me get rid of all those `list()` calls. I'll see what I can do as far as filtering out text nodes, but I was convinced that each "Shout" would be formatted the same (no extra nodes).

Comment: I see now that I'm going to have to do some more filtering, because `shout_feet[i].get_text()` is returning more than I would like. As for looping over `range()` I wanted to create a `Shout()` in one loop. A `Shout()` takes from both `shout_heads` and `shout_feet` and I didn't want to loop over one list directly.

Comment: @kaloncpu57: sorry, I had missed that. You can use `zip()` in that case.